# Multithreading accepts value and return value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, reporting-services

> Hi guys, I wrote the following code to return a pdf report. The code is based on a multi-threading sample code. Can you guys provide some feedback about it, I am new to mulit-thread.
>   Much appriciate ! 
>   Jeffery

```
public delegate void StreamResultDelegate(Stream streamResults);

public class GenerateReport
{
    private StreamResultDelegate callback;

    public GenerateReport(StreamResultDelegate _callback)
    {
        callback = _callback;
    }

    public void ThreadProc()
    {
        if (callback != null)
        {
            callback(Testing());
        }
    }

    public Stream Testing()
    {
        var reportsService = new ReportsService();
        var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
        byte[] pdfReportContents = reportsService.GetReport("/Rocket.Reports/RocketReport", nameValueCollection);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(pdfReportContents);
        return stream;
    }
}
```

//following

```
    [HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private Stream streamTesting = null;
    public void StreamResultCallBack(Stream s)
    {
        streamTesting = s;
    }

    public FileStreamResult GeneratePdfReport()
    {
        var g = new GenerateReport(_callback: new StreamResultDelegate(StreamResultCallBack));
        var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(g.ThreadProc));
        t.Start();
        t.Join();

        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Rockets_List_Printout.pdf");
        return new FileStreamResult(streamTesting, "application/pdf");
    }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use async controllers -> [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28VS.100%29.aspx) and stop using threads in controller methods=)

Comment: I agree on using async controllers but in his case it would still be useless because he's only doing 1 thing.

Comment: Hi ZippyV, you are right about this.This request only does one thing that is generating report.

Comment: Thanks Alexey and ZippyV, you are right about this.Since this request only does one thing that is generating report. So does my code actually offer any performance improvment in this situation? If not, in a web environment, since we have this server client request disconnect model, how does the multi-thread be helpful? Much appriciate !

Comment: I need a bit more info about your architecture to answer this. But if you just send one-way request(without response with report) and then check for report later and you are not using per call invocation model(asp.net mvc action or wcf per call) you possibly will gain some performance improvement,if your reporting solution is capable of creating reports in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is make a private object to store the result. It's the easiest way

update

```
public delegate void work_handler(Stream streamResults);
public class Report
{
 public object Result = null;

 private Thread workThread = new ...;

 public void Work(object param)
 {
  this.Result = ....;
  // signal finish. eg. if winapp use someControl.Invoke(signal_Handler);
  // for web app use this.Session["isDone"] = true;
 }

 // for .net 4.0
 private object param = null;
 public void Work() 
 {
  // for serial invoking
  var taskOption = System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning;
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => {... }, taskOption);

  // for multiple method parallel invoke
  System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke(() => { this.Result = genReport(param); }, () => {... }, () => {...});
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bonshington, can I ask you to provide a bit more details about how to achieve this. Cheers